# PHP5 to PHP7 upgrade causes encoding troubles in SQL Server database

Tags: php, sql-server, zend-framework, character-encoding, sqlsrv

We are having a PHP5.6 website project and we are about to re-launch it on PHP7.4.

Let's call them old environment and new environment. Old one still intact. Both are on different server machines.

Charsets (html meta tags) are set to utf-8.

Zend Framework 1 is involved in both. The database is on an SQL Server, shared by both environments. We use the SqlSrv driver to connect to the database (new environment), the old environment has PDO-Sql.

The encoding of the database is set to `Latin1_General_CI_AS`.

Information is getting inserted and selected into/from many tables (INSERT, SELECT). Html textfields and
textareas are in use.

In the old environment, any text written in textfields/-areas with special characters, such as umlauts, is being saved in the database in a corrupt form, like instead of ö there is Ã¶ in the database table. On the screen, after a select-statement however, it is shown as ö (clean!).

That was all okay until now, but now we have the new environment.

Let's say there is are old entries saved during the old environment era and we open the website on the new environment. The content is shown 1:1 as seen in the database table, in other words: corrupted. Which explains why anything that is saved with the help of the new environment is shown correctly on screen since special characters and umlauts are saved without any changes in the database table.

But the entries made with the new environment cannot be seen on the old environment website.

Using `utf8_encode` or `utf8_decode` didn't help much, either it looked even worse, or there is no text on screen to be seen neither.

Writing some script that changes the encoding in the table would cause mayhem, because since the old environment still in use, it can't be done that easy.

There are no encoding options mentioned in the options, that are used on the class called `Zend_Db_Adapter_Sqlsrv`.

Well, I don't trust `mb_detect_encoding` and yet we tried that, but it returned UTF-8 on the returned values from the tables.

So what would people recommend? I might have missed some facts, but I'll provide you with more information if needed.

Comment: The real problem is you didn't fix it before, despite knowing it was happening.

Comment: Clearly the best way to proceed is to work with UTF-8 in the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it was a project someone else did, we decided to update all tables and correct the values.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds very similar to a problem I've solved in the past. Unfortunately I solved it in ASP.NET, so I can only describe what I did and let you translate it into PHP.

So the issue probably arises because your old system is using a non-UTF-8 codepage, in my case the codepage was `windows-1252` which was fairly common at the time. The codepage determines the character coding that your code uses.

So on my more modern system what I had to do was force the codepage back to `windows-1252` while I was reading from the database. And then before rendering the page, set the content encoding to UTF-8.

So unless you are able to fix the problem at source, you basically have to hack your new system to continue operating the same way - which is a unfortunate but sometimes necessary.

The ASP.NET code looks like this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object Sender, EventArgs Args)
{
    // Set the encoding for building and rendering, then switch later to display as utf-8
    Response.Charset = "windows-1252"; // Hmmm... double check this
    Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1252");
}

protected void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
{
    // Now that all the character encoding has taken place, switch to utf-8 to force it to display this way...
    Response.Charset = "utf-8";
    Response.ContentEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
}
```

Hopefully that gives you enough to go on... its been a long time since I did this, but the pain still sticks in my mind!